# ListView not showing images properly

Tags: android

i have a listview that shows images downloaded from internet and have a custom layout for each row of the listview as below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00f"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wish"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

My getview method is as belows :

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v;

    final TextView tv;

    if(arg1 == null)
    { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) conn.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = lf.inflate(R.layout.layitem, arg2, false);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width / 2));
        // tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    }

    else
    {
        v = arg1;
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    if(arg0 < count)
    {
        Bitmap object = getImage(iurl[arg0]);
        tv.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(conn.getResources(), object));
        tv.setText(texts[arg0]);
    }

    else
    {
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wish);
        tv.setText("");

    }

    return v;
}
```

What i am trying to do is that my ListView has 20 rows and my no of records is less than 20.so the records fill up the rows and the rest have default background image.count is the actual no of records.

iurl is the array containing the name of images to obtain from server and texts is an array containing messages.

The problem is that arg0 does not go beyond 2 and all rows contain images indexed from 0 to 2 and when i scroll down that it changes image corresponding to the row number.

Can i put the correct image in the correct row at the first stance or it will only take up as it scrolls.

i am setting the width of the textview as per the width of the screen of the mobile.is it the right way to do .kindly update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an asyntask to get images from specific url on internet.
If you don't use thread to load images from internet, it will take a long time to load image and crash your programe

Comment: there is no problem of image loading .obviously i am doing through asynctask .images are loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you overriden getCount() method? It should return the number of items that are in the data set represented by this Adapter.

Comment: yes it is returning 20 as the listview shows 20 records but the problem is in the image that it shows. the images get properly populated as i scroll down

Comment: just to clarify, what about texts? the same problem?

Comment: no they show properly.either they load so quickly that their transition is not visible.